# Problem With IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

My site is working fine on mozila but when we go for IE 8 it gives error on status bar

Webpage error details:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Sun, 3 Apr 2011 16:26:29 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 8
Char: 3
Code: 0

on line 7 to 11
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#container').easyTabs({defaultContent:1});
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this web page publicly accessible? I work for a company called Changebase who have a product called “AOK Browse-It” which can check for IE8 compatibility. If you can send me the URL I can run it through this tool and post the results here. The tool can ‘spider’ static websites automatically, or for more complex web sites (user logon, dynamic content etc) we use ‘client-side capture’ which monitors web browsing using an agent on the PC.